# Reading an text file into an array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a text file that contains several words, all separated by spaces. I'm trying to read the file and then put it into an array, so that each word is a separate value in said array. I'm using this code, but when I run my program, it doesn't display anything (like it should.)

```
ifstream file ("words.txt");
if(file.is_open())
{
string wordArray[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    file >> wordArray[i];
    cout << i;
}
cout << "File is open.";
}
```

Nothing displays at all. I'm doing this in a void function, which isn't being passed anything currently, but I don't think that has anything to do with it. The code should at least display "File is open" or any number from 1 to 100, but I don't get anything. I don't understand why this isn't working, as I'm including iostream, string, fstream, iomanip, and sstream. If there's something simple I'm overlooking, please let me know.

Comment: Well, if nothing displays, it would suggest that your outermost `if` condition is false...

Comment: That's the thing, I don't understand why it won't open it. I put words.txt in every folder relating to the project just to be sure, and its also in the same folder as the executable that the debug creates.

Comment: one silly possible reason, that you have are using Windows and have not turned on display of file extensions, and have used e.g. Notepad to create a file that only apparently has the name "words.txt", but which in reality has the name "words.txt.txt". check in a command interpreter?

Comment: Alf, I just checked to make sure, and it's "words.txt", not "words.txt.txt" in the file explorer, the filename is only "words" and I saved it as a txt file instead of naming it "words.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your program probably isn't passing the statement in the `if` condition.
Try adding this to test your file is opening correctly:

```
if(file){
    // do all the file inputs
}
else{
    std::cerr << "could not open file words.txt" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: When I add that, it does tell me "could not open file words.txt" I don't know how I should fix it, as I'm not seeing any apparent flaws.

Comment: Make sure that the file is in the running directory of the compiled binary and that the file name is absolutely correct in the source as somebody else commented.

Comment: That did it. I had forgot to put it in one of the folders, so it's running now. Thank you!

Comment: To get more description of the error, you can try cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno);

Comment: @sj0h the chances of the error being anything other than that the file wasn't found, in this case, is pretty small.